# JavaFX Stage Size reset to parent

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, scene

Switching between scenes; the Parent scene is smaller than the rest of the scenes, so when I go back to the first scene, the stage holds the With/Hight of the last scene. My code to switch to the parent scene is listed below, how can I set it to get the original size of the parent stage/scene? Thanks!!

```
public void goBack(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;

    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    stage=(Stage) goBack.getScene().getWindow();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 331, 181);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: Perhaps call `sizeToScene` after you call `setScene`?

Comment: it didn't work, the same thing...

Comment: Create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are creating a new main scene. Its possible that you are not doing anything with that scene, and that is why nothing appears to be happening. Perhaps instead of doing this you should manually set the scene that already exists back to its original size. Without seeing the entire program I cant say for sure but this is a guess. Note also that it is unneccessary to generate a new main scene all the time. instead when switching scenes, the main scene should simply be set to invisible, until the program navigates back to it.

Comment: I am not doing anything special, going from one scene to the other, moving between scene, the stage gets bigger based on the FXML pane Hight/Wight, going bigger is fine, but when I try to go back to the first scene which happens to be the smallest window, the window won't size even if I force it to??